Finite field primitive element in Julia's Nemo package
In Julia's Nemo package, one may define a finite field F of order q as
using Nemo
F, x = finite_field(q,"x")

where x is (or better to say "seems to be") a primitive element of the field. Whenever F is a non-prime field, x is indeed a primitive element of F. However, for a prime field F, the returned value for x is always zero! What is wrong with (my perception of) Nemo?

How is the polynomial chosen for the field? Consider GF(2^4), there are two primitive polynomials, x^4 + x + 1 and x^4 + x^3 +1, both with primitive element x, and non-primitive but irreducible polynomial x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 with primitive element x +1. There are other primitive elements, in general for GF(2^n), there are totient(2^(n-1)) primitive elements. For GF(2^4), there are totient(15) = 8 primitive elements.
